# Six digit number probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have to solve next task: form numbers 1, 2 and 3 is randomly made six digit number. What is probability to number 1 to be only one time, number 2 to be two times and number 3 to be three times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**All possibilities:** Every 6-digit number that contains $1$, $2$ or $3$:

- First digit can be any of these numbers: $3$ possibilities.
- Second digit can also be any of these numbers: $3$ possibilities again...
  $$\vdots$$
- $6^{th}$ digit: $3$ possibilities again.

Overall: $3 \times 3 \times \dots \times 3 = 3^6 = 729$ possibilities.

**Beneficial possibilities:** Since $1+2+3=6$, you're technically ordering these digits:
$$1,\ 2,\ 2,\ 3,\ 3,\ 3$$
The ways you can order $6$ elements is $6! = 6 \times 5 \times 4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1 = 720$.

However, some of the elements are indistinguishable, so we need to reduce the ways you can order them by the ways you can swap out $2$'s for other $2$'s and $3$'s for other $3$'s. You can swap them out $2!$, and $3!$ ways.

So all the number of distinguishable ways to order these values is:
$$\frac{6!}{2! \times 3!} = \frac{6 \times 5 \times 4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1}{3 \times 2 \times 1 \times 2 \times 1} = 60.$$

**Probability:**
$$\Bbb{P}(\text{The number contains 1 digit-1, 2 digit-2's and 3 digit-3's}) = \frac{60}{729} \approx 0.0823 = 8.23\%$$

Comment: Does 9 digit number with letters 1, 2, 3, 4 = $4^9$?

Comment: Those swaps are not clear to me. Can you please give some example of swats 2! and 3!

Comment: Does 9 digit number with letters 1, 2, 3, 4 = $4^9$? - Yes. I'm editing this comment to give a further explanation.

Comment: Does 9 digit number with letters 1, 2, 3, 4 = $4^9$? - Yes.
The $1^{st}$ digit can either be $1, 2, 3,$ or $4$. - There are $4$ possibilites.

For **each** of those $4$ possible values the $2^{nd}$ digit can also be $1,2,3$, or $4$:
$$11, 12, 13, 14 \\
21, 22, 23, 24, \\
31, 32, 33, 34, \\
41, 42, 43, 44.$$
These are all the possiblities for the first $2$ digits: $4^2 = 16$ possibilities.

Comment: For **each** of these $16$ possibilities you can choose the $3^{rd}$ digit to be $1,2,3$, or $4$.
So **each** of the above values you can extend by either $1,2,3$, or $4$. That's $16 * 4 = 4^3 = 64$ possibilities to arrange them.

And so on, up to $9$ digits long.

Comment: "Those swaps are not clear to me. Can you please give some example of swats 2! and 3!" - Yes:

Imagine all the same the digits are colored differently: $1, 2, \color{red}2, 3, \color{red}3, \color{blue}3$. These are all **distinguishable** from each other.

There are $6!$ **unique** ways to order them.

Now let's imagine we took away the colors. Suddenly, some of those ordering ways became **indistinguishable** from each other. How many?

Comment: Well, if we swapped all the $3$'s that were previously different colored, we wouldn't notice any difference. Same for the $2$'s. There are respectively $3!$ and $2!$ of these indistinguishable groups.

So there are $\frac{6!}{3! \times 2!}$ ways to order them.

Comment: Thank you. So does indistinguishable - 133322, 122333, 221333, 223331, 333221, 333122?

Comment: Does it because 3! = 3 digits in group and 2! = 2 digits in group?

Answer (score 1):

Total number of 6 digit number made using $1,2,3$ only $=3^6\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(1)$

Number of numbers with one 1, two 2s and three 3s $=\frac{6!}{2!3!}=60\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(2)$

Probablity = $60/3^6\approx8.23\%$

Explanation for $(1)$:
Consider $6$ blank spaces. In each of those spaces we can fill $1,2$ or $3$ thus each has three choices and hence total is $3\times3\times3\times3\times3\times3=3^6$

Explanation for $(2)$:
Consider the number $122333$
We can rearrange the digits in $6!$  ways. But since $2$ and $3$ are repeated, we must divide the number of times they are repeated since we are over counting 2 times and 6 times repectively. You may also look at this http://www.mathwarehouse.com/probability/permutations-repeated-items.php

Comment: Hi, can you explain how you get this part $\frac{6!}{2!3!}$? Does 9 digit number with letters 1, 2, 3, 4 = $4^9$?

Comment: yes, you are correct.